# Sync docker images from artifactory to ACR

Tags: docker, artifactory, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

Is there a way I can push images from artifactory to ACR or pull it from ACR to artifactory anytime there is a new image:tag available in artifactory

Tried pipelines but no luck. Appreciate if anyone has a bash or python script to do it so I can schedule it from gitlab ci

Comment: I think automatically is not possible. What about a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Azure DevOps pipeline to achieve, this [pipeline code](https://gist.github.com/subudear/a7b76c70b729e13b129ffcfec9e13199) might help you.